# Implement workbox without node

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

Is it possible to implement workbox (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) in an application without node / npm (html + js + css)?
I still have not found this answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, yes, it should work just fine without using Node itself. There is also a CDN hosted version, so you won't need to use NPM to download it either.

If you check out their [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started) page, it'll show a simple starting example which just uses basic browser stuff.